# Dedicated Servers with Terminal Services

Tags: windows-terminal-services, dedicated-server

I need a dedicated server with Windows 2003/2008 Standard plus Terminal Services Client Access Licenses.

Can somebody recommend me some company which offers this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason why your hardware and software vendor needs to be the same company.  But most major server-hardware vendors have relationships with Microsoft to sell you both hardware and software.

The vendors that I know off the top of my head are Dell, HP, and CDW.  I am sure there are many others.  You will probably have to find the correct number for a business representative and give them a call.  The web sites of the vendors I mentioned aren't particularly easy to navigate when it comes to ordering bundles of software and hardware.

Answer (score 0):

If you can afford them, I would suggest [Rackspace](http://www.rackspace.com/solutions/managed_hosting/configurations/index.php).  They are very professional, I've had a very good experience with them, and they have plenty of [options](http://www.rackspace.com/solutions/managed_hosting/services/index.php) that you can add on to your server.  Good luck.